# Способ генерации HTML кода на PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, html5, вёрстка, шаблоны

Меня интересует, насколько правильно я генерирую динамику на сайте.
Допустим, есть основной шаблон (статика) и для генерации контента используется PHP, который в зависимости от условий генерирует HTML и "подставляет" верстку в шаблон:

```
<html>
 <head>
 ...
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="row-1">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="row-2">
   <?php content($_SESSION['id']); ?>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

В этом примере в месте, где нужна динамика, вызывается функция с аргументом id пользователя, который хранится в сессионной переменной:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 function content($id)
 {
     if(!empty($id))
     {
         $query = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT * FROM Post WHERE user_id = $id");
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
         {
             echo "<div>Пост $row[name]</div><br><p>$row[text]</p>";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         echo "<div>Для просмотра необходимо авторизоваться</div>";
     }
 }
```

Является ли такой способ генерации верстки приемлемым?
На разных ресурсах по этому вопросу дают противоречивые ответы, вроде, что генерация на стороне сервера требует много трафика или же наоборот, что это верный способ.
Помогите разобраться или подсказать более лучшее решение. Заранее спасибо!
P.S. Я знаю про паттерны (например MVC) и фреймворки с ними связанные, но меня на данный момент интересуют способы написания грамотного кода "своими руками".

Comment: `WHERE user_id = $id` содержит потенциальную уязвимость. В данном случае используйте `user_id = " . (int)$id` или
`sprintf("... WHERE user_id = %d", $id)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нареканий слишком много, попробуем разобраться.
Про ООП говорить не буду, но классы позволяют гораздо лучше организовать структуру проектов, чем простые глобальные функции.

- Не нужно вызывать `echo` без необходимости

Просто замените echo на return, и перенесите его в шаблон:

```
<?=content($_SESSION['id'])?>
```

- Нужно отделять данные от представления

Вынесите получение данных о пользователе в отдельную функцию:

```
function content($id) {
  $user = getUser(intval($id));
  if (empty($user)) return '...';
  return '...';
}
```

- Ведите разработку с максимально высоким уровнем вывода ошибок: `error_reporting(-1);`
  Так, вы бы увидели, что конструкции вида `"$a[some]"` генерируют лишние логи, потому как пытаются сначала обнаружить константу `some`, и только потом полагают, что это строка `Assume some as 'some'`. Обращения к жесткому диску для логирования могут существенно снизить производительность.
- Сделайте простой класс для генерации шаблонов
  Рано или поздно, html-код в функции `template` станент неуправляемым.
  Лучше вынести отображение данных о пользователе в отдельный шаблон.
  Класс для реализации подобного шаблона пишется элементарно с использованием фунции `extract`.

---

Пример такого шаблона:

```
class Template {
  private $tpl;
  public function __construct($tpl) {$this->tpl = $tpl;}
  // можно добавлять функции-helpers, доступные в темплейте через $this
  public function e($str) {return htmlspecialchars($str);}
  public function render($modelData) {
    try {
      // Делаем переменные доступными в шаблоне
      extract($modelData); // Можно также реализовать какой-нибудь \ArrayAccess и использовать тут $this->data
      ob_start();
      include $this->tpl;
    } catch (\Exception $e) { // Файл не найден, и т.п.
      ob_end_clean();
      throw $e;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();    
  }
}

// Usage:
// user.tpl
<div>
  <?php if (empty($user)): ?>
    <div>Для просмотра необходимо авторизоваться</div>
  <?php else:?>
    <div>Пост <?=$this->e($user['name'])?></div><br>
    <p><?=$this->e($user['text'])?></p>
  <?php endif?>
</div>
// controller
$tpl =  new Template(__DIR__.'/templates/layout.tpl');
$userTpl = new Template(__DIR__.'/templates/user.tpl');
echo $tpl->render([
 'userBlock' => $userTpl->render(['user' => $this->userProvider->find($id)])
]);
```

Comment: Я действительно уже смотрел в сторону ООП т. к.  многочисленные функции с разной генерацией становится тяжело поддерживать. Не подскажете, почему стоит избегать echo и я немного не понимаю полезность функции extract, если я правильно понял, она создает переменные из массива данных где ключ = имя переменной,  а значение = значение переменной. Что мешает создать нужные свойства в классе изначально? (применяя ООП) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Написал пример простейшего класса темплейта.

Comment: @vp_arth, всегда оставляю такой комментарий: не учите плохому, в вашем коде вывод не защищен от XSS, добавьте htmlspecialchars

Comment: @TotalPusher, nice catch, как говорят большие братья с enSO =)

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам глянуть в сторону шаблонизаторов, вы можете реализовать всю логику сами, так например использовать паттерн `HMVC`, но сам вывод динамических данных реализовать по средствам `PHP/JS` Шаблонизаторов. Из `PHP` Шаблонизаторов отмечу как самый простой на мой взгляд это `Twig`, с `JS` ситуация сложнее, так как в целом в `JS` Нет такого понятия как «шаблонизатор», просто у фреймворков на `JS` Есть своя удобная реализация работы с `DOM`, которая легко позволяет нам выводить динамические данные на страницу.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не стоит использовать HTML код в PHP. Лучше сделать SQL-select и вернуть массив  и сделать это в самом верху к примеру:

   ```
   $content = content($_SESSION['id']);
   if($content['code'] !== 200) {
       $error['code'] = 403;
       $error['message'] = 'Необходимо авторизоваться.';
   }
   ```

Тогда твоя функция **content();** может выглядеть вот так.

```
function content($id) {
    if(!empty($id)) {
      $query = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT * FROM Post WHERE user_id = $id");
      return ['code'=>200, 'posts'=>mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)];
    } else {
      return ['code'=>403, 'message'=> 'Unauthorized']
    }
}
```

А в html шаблоне уже использовать [Альтернативный Синтаксис Управляющих Структур](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)
и выводить.

```html
<div class = "posts">
<? foreach($content['posts'] as $post): ?>
  <div class = "post">
    <div>
      <?=$post['name'];?>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <?=$post['text'];?>
    </div>
  </div>
<? endforeach; ?>
</div>
```